# Check if Argument is Empty or Not Same

Tags: c++, if-statement, arguments

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argv[1] == ""){
        cout << "please put something" << endl;
    }else if(argv[1] == "string"){
        cout << "yeah string" << endl;
    }else if(argv[1] == "integer"){
        cout << "yeah integer" << endl;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong: I try to check if argument supplied for argv[1] is empty so it will be `false` and application will exit, so please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Are you aware of `strcmp` and `strlen`?

Comment: i'm new into c++ world, so not much info i know about function in c++, most of the time i use php in my coding, but now i plan to learn c++..

Comment: Oh I was under the impression you are a c programmer moving to c++, but no. So scratch my first comment. Don't learn `strcpy` & `strlen` learn `std::string` instead. :)

Comment: other people answers make me understand what i wrong, btw thank also to you.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everybody is giving you a different answer. And in fact everybody is right.

The signature of main, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is inherited from C.
In C strings are pointer to `char`. When you use operator`==` on them, you only compare pointer value.

The C way to compare string content is to use `strcmp`.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "integer") == 0){
```

It is safer and easier for you to do it the C++ way.

```
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "integer"){
```

This line create a temporary std::string from `argv[1]`. you must include `string` for this to work.

Finally check if `argc == 2` in order to know if an argument was supplied.
It is true that argv is null terminated by the [standard 3.6.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) but it definitely
make things clearer to check that argv is indeed equal to 2.

Comment: so we need to convert char into string before we do comparison, thank for nice example and answers..  :)

Answer (score 4):

Can't use `==` for argv[] as it's `char*` type, use strcmp instead.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1){
        cout << "please put something" << endl;
    }else if(strcmp(argv[1], "string") == 0){
        cout << "yeah string" << endl;
    }else if (strcmp(argv[1], "integer") == 0){
        cout << "yeah integer" << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Or you need to make a copy of argv[1] to std::string then you can use `==` operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to code in C++ you can use `std::string`, include its header:

```
#include <string>
```

Convert the first argument to `std::string` and use its `operator==`:

```
std::string first = argv[1];

if(first == ""){
    cout << "please put something" << endl;
}else if(first == "string"){
    cout << "yeah string" << endl;
}else if(first == "integer"){
    cout << "yeah integer" << endl;
}
```

Comparison of `char *` to string literals doesn't make sense, if you make a `std::string` out of `argv[1]` then it's a different story, it will work as you expected.

But, you should check the number of arguments supplied to the program by the user first, it's in `argc`.

Comment: i thought argv[1] is string (because result is in string), but now i know it, thank.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First check if argc > 1. Otherwise, you're accessing an invalid memory.

```
if(argc < 2){
    cout << "please put something" << endl;
}else if(argv[1] == "string"){
    cout << "yeah string" << endl;
}else if(argv[1] == "integer"){
    cout << "yeah integer" << endl;
}
```

Comment: "Otherwise, you're accessing an invalid memory." - Nope, since `argv` is NULL-terminated - even if there are no arguments, `argv[1]` is valid, it's just `NULL`.

Comment: so if i make string(argv[1]) == NULL it's make sense or not ?

Comment: (string(argv[1]) == NULL) works exactly the same as (argc < 2). The reason is that in standard C, the last value of the argv array is always NULL. That is as long as your compiler implements the standard...

Answer (score 0):

```
         #include <string>
         #include <iostream>
```

This will use the c++ way to compare strings. The safer way.
Convert the first argument to std::string, then use the string::compare function

```
          std::string inString = argv[1];

          if(inString.compare("") != 0) 
          {
             std::cout << "please put something in" << std::endl;
          }
          else if(inString.compare("string") == 0 ){
             std::cout << "yeah you got a string" << std::endl;
          }
          else if(inString.compare("integer") == 0)
          {
             std::cout << "yeah you got an integer" << std::endl;
          }
```

Note: with string::compare(string or pointer to a string) see reference on this function. Relation between the string and what you are comparing to:

0 They compare equal.  If compare yields < 0, either the value of the first character that does not match is lower in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is shorter. If >0, then either the value of the first character that does not match is greater in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is longer.